# SQL Server Except Query not return Correct Asnwer

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_User_not_regestired_companies]
    @userId as int
AS
BEGIN
    select CompanyId, Name  
    from Company

    except

    select CompanyId, Name    
    from SecurityUserCompanyLevel
    where UserId = @userId 
END
```

My problem is when I write `CompanyId` in select clause it will return the correct answer. When I write `Name` in select clause it will return a list of all companies

Comment: because same `CompanyId, Name` are not exist in `SecurityUserCompanyLevel` table

Comment: Logically if it's returning all, the the name for the @userID passed in for table SecurityUserCompanyLevel doesn't match the name field in the company table.  verify the name fields match by doing an equalty check between both tables...  For example:  `Select S.Name, C.Name, userID from Company C RIGHT JOIN SecurityUserCompanyLevel  S on S.Name = C.Name where C.Name is null`  if records are returned are they for the userID passed in?  if so likely data integrity problem... meaning names between tables don't match.

Comment: Then it may look like the same name but actually be different.  And why do you have name in two tables?

Comment: Can you give examples of the data, the results you are getting, and the results you are trying to get instead?

Comment: To troubleshoot the data, you can try doing a full outer join on your keys and see what exists in each of the tables for the information you've passed it.

Comment: Not directly related to your question but you might want to read this. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix